# Opening .tblk file with root privileges

Tags: macos, vpn

Following the [setup instructions for Tunnelblick](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/osx10.10-openvpn-tunnelblick) I want to open the renamed .tblk file

After opening it nothing happens and no prompt in the tunnelblick app
I suspect this is because I am not opening it as administrator and it is a file downloaded from the internet.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the file, go under informations, scroll down to permissions and click on the lock. Then enter your administrator password to unlock it. Then, it you're not allowed to read, write and execute click on the +, select your username on the list and press select. Then change the combobox to read, write execute.

Then, you should be able to open your file by right clicking and clicking on open with -> Tunnelblick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I don't know exactly what helped but I set me as the owner of zip file and then it could be opened with Tunnelblick.

Renaming the file to .tblk didn't work as it failed with this error:

> An internal Tunnelblick error occurred: allFilesAreReasonableIn: Not a
>   folder, .conf, or .ovpn: /Users/mhla/Downloads/openvpn.tblk

So I extracted the zip file and selected all .ovpn files and opened it at once with Tunnelblick. It asked me if I want to install it just for myself or all users and then it was installed correctly.